# error: exportArchive: The operation couldn’t be completed. (IDEDistributionErrorDomain error 3.)

Tags: ios, build, release, xcodebuild

I am building iOS project on command line using xcodebuild. Building with Release configuration is ok which created and App.xcarchive. Then I am trying to export archive for App Store IPA using,

```
xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath App.xcarchive -exportPath ~/output/ -exportOptionsPlist appstore.plist
```

My appstore.plist,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>teamID</key>
<string>T3AM1D</string>
<key>method</key>
<string>app-store</string>
</dict>
</plist
```

This gives me error,

> error: exportArchive: The operation couldn’t be completed.(IDEDistributionErrorDomain error 3.)

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally I was able to solve this issue.

### Solution Steps

1. Make sure all profiles and certificates are setup successfully in Mac
2. Make sure no red mark is shown from Xcode, For example `Xcode`->`targets`->`Build settings` ->`Profiles and signing identity + team`
3. Make sure that all targets including MainApp, Widgets, Extensions are also configures without issue
4. Make sure that all capabilities, appgroup and keychains are OK
5. Important: Make sure that from `Xcode` -> `Product` -> `Archive` -> `export to App Store IPA` ran at least one time
6. When running xcodebuild from command line, make sure that `Xcode` is closed

Hope this helps